# Issues calling the field of an object to use in a method

Tags: java

I am having an issue using the value of a field and I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. My goal is to use the shift field from the Key Object to add its value to a char value. However, I keep getting the error "shift cannot be resolved or is not a field" when I call the object's field. I appear to have created the constructor, instanced the object, and sent it over correctly.

```
public class Key {
    private int ID;
    private int shift;

    public Key(int ID, int shift) {
        ID = this.ID;
        shift = this.shift;
        //Here is the constructor for the object
    }
}
```

Instanced in a separate class

```
public void composeHelper() {
    Key key1 = new Key(1, 3);
    ....
    ....
       
    encryptedMessage = message1.Encrypt(message, key1);
}
```

But I get the error shift cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
public String Encrypt(String message, Object key1) {         
    String Encrypted = "";
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(message);
    while (scn.hasNextLine()){   
        String line = scn.nextLine();
        String sEncrypted = "";         
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            sEncrypted += (char)(line.charAt(i) + key1.shift);                         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see 2 issues, first in constructor: it should be this.shift = shift; etc. and second: your fields should be public to be accessed from outside the class

Comment: Here see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLqLgLJ-Ts0&ab_channel=Access2Learn it will help you understand accessors and modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is assigning the fields to the parameters:

```
public Key(int ID, int shift) {
    ID = this.ID;
    shift = this.shift;
}
```

but you want the opposite:

```
public Key(int ID, int shift) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.shift = shift;
}
```

---

The `Encrypt()` method accepts `Object`, so the code in the method can only access fields/methods of the `Object` class. Change the method parameter type to `Key`:

```
public String Encrypt(String message, Object key1) { // <-- change to Key
    // other code         
    sEncrypted += (char)(line.charAt(i) + key1.shift;
}
```

Like this:

```
public String Encrypt(String message, Key key1) {
```

or even better, follow java naming conventions:

```
public String encrypt(String message, Key key) {
```

Comment: @tgdavies Huh? The type of `key1` is `Key`, not `Object`. The `Encrypt()` method accepts `Object` and `key1` is an `Object`.

Comment: Specifying the Key  key1 did the trick. Is there a point to using Object <objectname> like i had done?

Comment: No point if you want to invoke a method but actually you don't need to: make the parameter `Object` so you can encrypt anything, and pass `key1.shift` instead of `key1`!